# Diamond - presence of oxygen and elevated temperature. What would happen?

Tags: thermodynamics

Let's say I have a 1 cm3 diamond and I put it into an oven where the temperature is about 400 ∘C. We all know that diamond oxidizes. Would it evaporate or turn into graphite? If so, what would be the rate of reaction? Is there some way to calculate it?

From Wikipedia:

Above 1700 ∘C (1973 K/3583 ∘F) in vacuum or oxygen-free atmosphere, diamond converts into graphite; in air, transformation starts at ≈700 ∘C. Diamond's ignition point is 720−800 ∘C in oxygen and 850−1000 ∘C in air.
[....]

But diamonds (sp3 carbon) are unstable against high temperature (above about 400 ∘C (752 ∘F)) under atmospheric pressure. The structure gradually changes into sp2 carbon above this temperature. Thus, diamonds should be reduced under this temperature.

So even if the diamond doesn't reach the temperature of 700 ∘C it still oxidizes. That's why I'm asking.

Comment: Have you looked up the melting point? Boilding point? or anything towards this your self? - It would help if you could explain ...   This question as stated is really too broad and may also be better at Chemistry Stack Exchange

Comment: Wikipedia says: "Above 1700 °C (1973 K / 3583 °F) in vacuum or oxygen-free atmosphere, diamond converts to graphite; in air, transformation starts at ~700 °C.[32] Diamond's ignition point is 720–800 °C in oxygen and 850–1000 °C in air. [...]  But diamonds (sp3C) are unstable against high temperature (above about 400 °C (752 °F)) under atmospheric pressure. The structure gradually changes into sp2C above this temperature. Thus, diamonds should be reduced under this temperature." So even if the diamond doesn't reach the temperature of 700 it still oxidizes. That's why I'm asking.

Comment: Great - please put that information in your question and explain what research you have done, then you will be able to more tightly define exactly what you know and exactly what you are asking. .. The question may still be better for Chemistry SE ....

Comment: Quote --- But diamonds (sp3C) are unstable against high temperature (above about 400 °C (752 °F)) under atmospheric pressure. The structure gradually changes into sp2C above this temperature. Thus, diamonds should be reduced under this temperature. --- this is not reduction, just a change from diamond to graphite structure

Comment: before it reaches 700 degC, it doesn't oxidize but has phase change from diamond sp3 structure to graphite sp2 carbon structure.